# Some keys in session_kwargs are not supported at this time: %s', dict_keys(['learning_rate'])

Tags: tensorflow, keras, text-processing

I am trying to build a movie rating predictor based on the reviews. I am using Keras with tensorflow as backend. I downloaded Tensorflow and keras using Anaconda. X and y in the code are numpy arrays. I am trying to run the following code,

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.callbacks import History
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Dropout
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.core import Flatten
from keras.layers import Embedding
model = Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 10))
model.add(keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(Dense(17, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))


model.add(Dense(5, activation = 'softmax'))
optimizer = keras.optimizers.sgd(lr = 0.1)

model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = optimizer, metrics = ['accuracy'], learning_rate = 0.2)
history = model.fit(X_train_indices, y_train_oh,batch_size = 128,epochs = 25, verbose = 1)
print(model.summary())
```

And I get the following error message,

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-a638769cab16> in <module>()
----> 1 history = model.fit(X_train_indices, y_train_oh,batch_size = 128,epochs = 25, verbose = 1)
      2 print(model.summary())

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1006         else:
   1007             ins = x + y + sample_weights
-> 1008         self._make_train_function()
   1009         f = self.train_function
   1010 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _make_train_function(self)
    506                     updates=updates,
    507                     name='train_function',
--> 508                     **self._function_kwargs)
    509 
    510     def _make_test_function(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in function(inputs, outputs, updates, **kwargs)
   2693                 msg = 'Invalid argument "%s" passed to K.function with TensorFlow backend' % key
   2694                 raise ValueError(msg)
-> 2695     return Function(inputs, outputs, updates=updates, **kwargs)
   2696 
   2697 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in __init__(self, inputs, outputs, updates, name, **session_kwargs)
   2540             raise ValueError('Some keys in session_kwargs are not '
   2541                              'supported at this '
-> 2542                              'time: %s', session_kwargs.keys())
   2543         self._callable_fn = None
   2544         self._feed_arrays = None

ValueError: ('Some keys in session_kwargs are not supported at this time: %s', dict_keys(['learning_rate']))
```

The shape of input X_train_indices is 6396x28 and the shape of y_train_oh is 6396x5.

If I remove the embedding and the GlobalAveragePooling1D layer from the model it works but gives a very poor accuracy of just 27% and the accuracy fluctuates wildly.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`learning_rate` is not a parameter of `model.compile`, it is a parameter for the optimizer (usually called `lr`). Just remove that parameter from your call.

Comment: Thanks, @Matias Valdenegro it runs now. But still, I am not able to improve accuracy. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Ish That's a different problem, comments are not meant for that. Start by tuning the learning rate, 0.1 might be too high.

Comment: Ok sorry. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Any time that you are passing a parameter to the wrong function, you might get such errors. I remember once I passed the call_back parameter to the compiler instead of passing it to the model.fit.

so check your functions and make sure you are passing right accorguments.